# CSS: displaying one particular icon from an image file

Tags: css

How does one set the CSS `background-image` property to just load one particular icon from a larger image?

For example, jQuery UI themes its Dialog widget using the following PNG image file:
http://dev.jqueryui.com/browser/trunk/themes/base/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png, which encodes a bunch of icons in it. Then, as demoed in http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog the bottom right resize handle loads the very last icon from the PNG.

Using Firebug I can see a bunch of CSS properties like `ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se` applied that refers to `url(ui-icons.xx.png)`, but nothing about selecting a particular icon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is actually a CSS sprite technique.

[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

use

[background-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position)

property

> If a background image has been
>   specified, this property specifies its
>   initial position. If only one value is
>   specified, the second value is assumed
>   to be 'center'. If at least one value
>   is not a keyword, then the first value
>   represents the horizontal position and
>   the second represents the vertical
>   position. Negative  and
>    values are allowed.

Eg:

```
body { background: url("banner.jpeg") right top }    /* 100%   0% */
body { background: url("banner.jpeg") top center }   /*  50%   0% */
body { background: url("banner.jpeg") center }       /*  50%  50% */
body { background: url("banner.jpeg") bottom }       /*  50% 100% */
```

> The background CSS property is a
>   shorthand property for setting the
>   individual background property values
>   in a single place in the style sheet.
>   background can be used to set the
>   values for one or more of:
>   background-color, background-image,
>   background-position,
>   background-repeat,
>   background-attachment.

```
.PosBG { 
  background-image: url("logo.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[image: Under the covers...]

The anchor elements are fixed size and the background is set to the image containing all of the icons but the background-position property is specified to shift the background-image so that only the desired icon from the image is displayed.

Take a look at [A List Apart's explaination of the technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following:

```
background-image: url('yourimage.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 25px 0px;
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp for more on background-position

Comment: The above link is now broken. Use this instead: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: @javid i just read your working useful link but in that they are telling sprite technology is useful and explain also i agree with w3school. but what about this statement "A web page with many images can take a long time to load and generates multiple server requests." for seperating images any how You have to call image multiple time by using url property.